# I can't make a sphere blend, with transparency, with another (Earth - Clouds)

Tags: transparency

sorry for the noob question, but I'm following [this](https://youtu.be/9Q8PwcDzb8Y?t=953) tutorial and when comes the part to make the Earth appear "behind" the clouds, it doesn't work. I'm stuck at this for a while and I can use some help. Thank you! :)

Images:
[image: Earth]

[image: Clouds]

Comment: could you please pack the images (File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sure. Here it is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12cPhxTa6vx04lX4CeUSI4mTHWi3fEcU_/view?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: it works fine in Cycles (Properties panel > Render > Render Engine > Cycles), you're currently in Eevee, there must be a setting for transparency in Eevee but I don't know enough about it

Comment: this might help, but I think Eevee evolves quickly so it could have changed since: https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/a4i8bu/can_eevee_not_do_transparency_or_is_28_still_have/

Comment: @moonboots Thank you. Switching the rending engine did the trick. And I even heard that it's more realistic, so it's all good. :)

Comment: As @moonboots said, switching to cycles render engine did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in the material settings.
Go to *Material Properties > Settings > Blend Mode* and change from *Opaque* to *Alpha Blend*.